# Google Chrome is blurry on Ubuntu 23.04 (Wayland + Nvidia 3050 Ti HiDPI screen with 200% scaling)

Tags: nvidia, google-chrome, wayland, scaling, hdpi

I'm using Ubuntu 23.04 on my Dell XPS 9520 (Nvidia 3050 Ti) with the latest drivers from Canonical repos. The current version is 530, but the problem existed on 525 too.

For some reason, Google Chrome looks extremely blurry on my 4k screen with 200% scaling.

The `chrome://flags` **Ozone** attribute has a `Wayland` value.

The strangest thing is launching the app from the terminal with `--force-device-scale-factor=2` gives a sharp piece of Chrome interface which doesn't listen to a cursor and cannot be resized. I can only stop the process in the terminal.

All other software, including the .deb version of Firefox and proprietary tools, works like a charm.

Is there anything I can do to force the proper rendering of Chrome on my laptop?

Answer (score 8):

I have been experiencing the same thing on Fedora with a 4k screen and 2x scaling. Chrome version 112 was the last version which worked normally for me.

It seems to be caused by the new Wayland fractional scaling feature. What worked for me was turning it off using `--disable-features=WaylandFractionalScaleV1`.

Comment: You are my eyes saver. Thank you for the suggestion, it works perfectly.

Comment: Any way to set it permanently in chrome without a need to change launcher?

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to "chrome://flags" in your chrome browser
2. Search "Preferred Ozone platform"
3. Select "Wayland" option
4. Restart

[image: Select Wayland]

Answer (score 0):

As described in another answer, the solusion is adding `--disable-features=WaylandFractionalScaleV1`.

If you want to add the option '--disable-features=WaylandFractionalScaleV1` to the system chrome icon, you can:

1. Find the Desktop Entry: The desktop entry for Chrome is likely located in /usr/share/applications/ named something like google-chrome.desktop or in ~/.local/share/applications/ if you have a custom or per-user shortcut.
2. Edit the Desktop Entry by add `--disable-features=WaylandFractionalScaleV1` to `Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable %U` make it:

```
Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --disable-features=WaylandFractionalScaleV1 %U
```

Log out and re log in to make the change effect.